# How to create flow so that the Account owner always follows records

Tags: apex, chatter, flow, visual-workflow

How can I create a flow that the Account owner would automatically follow the account record in chatter regardless of which user created the record.

If this is not possible can it be done using Apex. Any sample code would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is this still an open question?

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson ! You suggestion worked. I was also able to implement it using flow.

Comment: Cool! Feel free to post your own solution as an answer. Just make sure you accept one eventually so the community can tell you got it resolved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if what you want can be achieved via flow, but it can via `Apex`, using the `EntitySubscription` [object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm).

Example:

```
EntitySubscription follow = new EntitySubscription(
    ParentId = accountToFollow.Id, SubscriberId = accountToFollow.OwnerId
);
insert follow;
```